# How to combine two aggregate functions in a single query?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to analyse Average (Total # comments per Content created) per day. I have a list of 
1. # of comments, 
2. # of contents created
day wise. But I am unable to get them all in an output as columns of  same table.

Google BigQuery.

### Problem is -

#### Code 1 :

It either shows *unrecognized name* `comment_per_UGC` when I club the previous column's result for next column.

#### Code 2:

If I use, `avg(sum(comments)/count(distinct (postId)))`, an error saying *aggregate of aggregate functions not allowed*.

Code 1 -

```
select date_posted, count(*) as Commentors, sum(comments) as comment, 
count(distinct (postId)) as UGC, sum(comments)/count(distinct (postId)) 
as comment_per_UGC, avg(comment_per_UGC) as Overall_Avg_UGC
```

Code 2 -

```
select date_posted, count(*) as Commentors, sum(comments) as comment, 
count(distinct (postId)) as UGC, sum(comments)/count(distinct (postId)) 
as comment_per_UGC, avg(sum(comments)/count(distinct (postId))) as 
Overall_Avg_UGC
```

Expected output - Average (comment_per_UGC) as the last column (Column #6)

Comment: `SUM/COUNT` by definition is the `AVG`, meaning your `comment_per_UGC` is already average. Unless you are missing some details of your use-case -  if so - update your question with more details and at least provide full query instead of just select list, so we see your logic of grouping

Answer (score 0):

Try with a subquery;

```
    Select date_posted,avg(comment_per_UGC) from (    
    select date_posted, count(*) as Commentors, sum(comments) as comment, 
        count(distinct (postId)) as UGC, sum(comments)/count(distinct (postId)) 
        as comment_per_UGC


    ) t
group by date_posted
```

Comment: t.* throws an error. How do we group the answer by `date_posted`?

Comment: Just try replacing t.* with date_posted and add group by date_posted at the end of the query. Error is expected as there is aggregation, editing the answer.